# java.sql.SQLException: Column 'nombreGarcia' not found. why?

Tags: java

I cant connect my db with my java aplication and I really dont know whts wrong with it, comeone cant help me, please

```
 try {
        
        Connection miconexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/concesionario","root","password");
        
        // 2.PASO CREAR PASO STAMENT.
        
        Statement miStatement = miconexion.createStatement();
        
        
        //3.PASO EJECUTAR MY SQL.
        
        ResultSet miresulset = miStatement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CLIENTES");
        
        //4.PASO RECORRER EL RESULSET
        
        while(miresulset.next()) {
            
            System.out.println(miresulset.getString("dni" + miresulset.getString("nombre" + "" + miresulset.getString("apellido"))));
            
        }
        
    }catch(Exception e) {
        
        System.out.println("NO CONECTA");
        e.printStackTrace();
        
    }
```

Comment: Because table `CLIENTES` doesn't have a column named `nombreGarcia`. What is so difficult to understand about that error message?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean to write `System.out.println(miresulset.getString("dni") + miresulset.getString("nombre") + "" + miresulset.getString("apellido"))`, where the 3 calls to `getString` are immediately completed with a `)` right there, instead of at the end?

Comment: yes u are right whas wrong the code. thanks.

Comment: the code was wrote wrong . ofcourse dosent exist.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
System.out.println(miresulset.getString("dni" + miresulset.getString("nombre" + "" + miresulset.getString("apellido"))));
```

adds whatever is found as apellido to "nombre". The value happens to be "Garcia", hence the `String` of nombreGarcia in the error. This is as far as I can go with helping you without further information from your part.